# Find + Object + V-ed

Tags: grammar

On p.2 in the book "Shai & et al. (2004), *Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms*, Cambridge University Press", I found the following sentence:

> That, in turn, increased the chance that the next random food delivery would **find each bird engaged** in that activity again.

Normally I see either the structure *Find + Object + V-infinitive* or *Find + Object + V-ing* but here it's *find + object + v-ed*. So I was wondering if this is a typo or it's some kind of grammar usage that I haven't known of?

Comment: "Engaged" is here an adjective, not a verb. The PP "in that activity again" is complement of "engaged", and the AdjP "engaged in that activity again" modifies "bird".

Comment: This is _[to be_ deletion](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/cls/pcls/1973/00000009/00000001/art00005?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf). _To be_ is understood and can be reinserted without changing anything but the number of syllables. That rule normally converts an infinitive VP starting with _be_ into a participle VP, using whatever's left after _be_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regard it as "find+object+v-ed".
Actually nouns can be modified with a v-ed and it's more like an adjective here,so you can also think it's a "find+object" and the object is modified with a v-ed.

It's how I understand it.

Comment: @KillingTime Do you happen to see some other example of this usage? I can't recall seeing it elsewhere.

Comment: The final term after found+object is often adjectival even if it's an -ing form, such as "He found the book disappointing", "He found the class boring". As for past participle forms, I can find a lot of examples like "You may find yourself overwhelmed by your feelings" where "overwhelmed" is an adjective derived from the past participle. Google also finds a lot of cases like "I found it broken", " If you have ever got to your parked car and found it smashed up...", etc.

Comment: Yes, "engaged" is here an adjective, not a verb. The PP "in that activity again" is complement of "engaged", and the AdjP "engaged in that activity again" modifies "bird".

Comment: @BillJ What about interpreting the sentence in terms of ellipsis, i.e: "would find (that) each bird engaged in that activity again.", where "that" is omitted?

Comment: @TranKhanh I'm surprised that you approved an answer that is clearly wrong because it suggests that "engaged" is a verb, when it'a actually an adjective!

Comment: @BillJ QT did mention that it's *more like an adjective*, that's why I accepted. But after reviewing carefully, I agree that it should be updated.